# Rails using a different version of Ruby from the rest of the sytem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My installation of Rails seems to be using a different version of Ruby from the version of Ruby on the rest of my system:

```
$ rails --version

Rails 5 requires Ruby 2.2.2 or newer.

You're running
  ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]

Please upgrade to Ruby 2.2.2 or newer to continue.
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

Why is this? I installed Rails with `sudo gem install rails`. I'm on OSX and don't remember how I installed Ruby.

Comment: what is the output of `$ which rails` and `$ which ruby`?

Comment: What do you have in your `gemfile`?

Comment: Use RBenv or RVM to handle the versions of ruby installed on your system and NEVER install gems with sudo. Its not only unsafe but it will mess up the file permissions.

Comment: `sudo gem install rails` ... and there's your problem. It's much, much easier to manage your ruby/gem versions via a tool like `rbenv`. Don't use the built-in version, and don't use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OSX comes ruby installed as default. If you need more late versions of ruby, you need to follow this guide: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html